# Need help making iframe responsive

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe, size, iframe-resizer

I have an iframe I want to add to my React.js website. The src of the iframe links to another responsive website (hereby known as "gallery"). This means the width and height of gallery will change depending on the website size. How do I adjust the width/height/styling of the iframe so that like gallery, the iframe also shows all of the webpage contents regardless of screen size?

I tried setting the width and height of the iframe to 100%. While the iframe did span the entire width of the device screen regardless of size, setting the height to 100% unfortunately did not do what I wanted it to. Only a small part of the iframe showed up and the rest was cut off with a scrolling bar. If I set scrolling to "no", the same small part of the iframe would still only show.

I also tried hardcoding the height of the iframe. If I set the height large enough to show all contents on larger screens, some of the content would still be cut off on smaller screens. If I set the height large enough for smaller screens like smartphones, there would be a ton of empty space at the bottom of my website on larger screens that I didn't want.

I am not sure what to do. Some of the things I tried (such as setting height to 100% and setting scrolling to no) were from stackoverflow itself, so I have tried looking at other posts. I'm not sure what to do.

I can share code if needed; this is a personal project, not a school project, so there aren't any consequences of sharing code.

Thanks in advance for the help!

My HTML CODE -

```html
<div class = "container">
    <iframe title = "gallery" class = "responsive" src="LINK" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen scrolling="no">
    </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

MY CSS CODE -

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 66.66%; 
}

.responsive {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Please do share code and your technology choices if your code does not make them apparent. I have worked with iframes like this before and I would expect what you have described to have worked. Iframes respect their own rendered size.

Comment: @DeanJames updated the post with code relevant to the iframe. Note that LINK is to be replaced with the actual link.

Comment: I think the issue is within the iframe itself. Your iframe html etc. looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is way more complex than it should be, at one point a solution was part of the HTML 4 spec, but it got dropped I expect due to being to hard to reliable work out the night of the content.

I wrote a library a while ago that tackles these problems, it is called [iframe-resize-react](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer-react) and should work in most situations